# Can these sorts of if/else statements be boiled down with a walrus operator?

Tags: python, python-assignment-expression

I have read up blogs and tutorials around the `:=` operator but I am still trying to wrap my head around how to know *when* to use it. I understand its purpose is to improvement maintainability, avoiding potential code duplication, and assignments in comprehensions but I am wondering if it can be used to replaced something like:

```
n = 2
for m in [1,2,3,-9,5]:
    if m > n:
        n = m
```

Yes, I know I can sort the list. This question is less about algorithm discussions but more about how to identify when/where to use the `:=` operator.

Comment: Are you looking for `n = max([1, 2, 3, -9, 5])`?

Comment: essentially yes (but lets say we cannot call `max`)

Comment: @wjandrea: Since `max` also accepts varargs, you don't even need the brackets, `n = max(1, 2, 3, -9, 5)` works too (though it's obviously rather silly when they're all literals).

Comment: Honestly, the more I used assignment expressions, the less I keep using them. My prevailing thought when coming back to them after a period of time is "eww". They're like conditional expressions in other languages where it's really easy to use them in places that turn perfectly readable code into a compacted mess. Also, I don't see how it could cleanly help here.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yeah, I'm assuming the list is defined elsewhere in the real code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: I use them all the time *for the things that are uglier without them*, e.g. reading a file by block with `while block := f.read(BLOCKSIZE):` being better than `while True:`, `block = f.read(BLOCKSIZE)`, `if not block: break`. But yes, outside of code golf, you're better off avoiding them most of the time.

Comment: Did you try searching something like "when to use walrus operator in python"? [This Real Python article](https://realpython.com/python-walrus-operator/) looks good. In the code here on the other hand, I don't even see where you'd put a walrus.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't bother with the walrus, since it doesn't aid you in any way in this sort of scenario. You could use a conditional expression though:

```
for m in [1,2,3,-9,5]:
    n = m if m > n else n
```

It's subtly different in behavior (it will *always* reassign `n`, which can make a difference if `n` is a more complex expression or a weirdo `@property` or the like), but it's otherwise equivalent.

The only use for a walrus would be to maintain a *running* maximum in a listcomp or the like, e.g.

```
n = 2
running_maximums = [n := m if m > n else n for m in [1,2,3,-9,5]]
print(running_maximums)
print(f'n={n}')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P0/BVsGIq6g0Ly8zLz0@N7EiM7c0txgoGJ2nYGWrkKuQmQYk7BTyFFJzilOBVFp@EUg0TyHaUMdIx1hH11LHNDaWq6AoM69EA90cTah4mnqebXVerbrm//8A)

which outputs:

```
[2, 2, 3, 3, 5]
n=5
```

Note that mixing the conditional expression with a listcomp makes for *very* hard to read code, and `itertools.accumulate` could do this job with rather less hand-rolled ugliness, with something like `running_maximums = list(accumulate([1,2,3,-9,5], max, initial=n))`. Or if you only want new values in the output when they change, `[n := m for m in [1,2,3,-9,5] if m > n]`. This is all fairly contrived and unlikely to be useful in most cases, but it's the best I can give you on useful use of the walrus in this scenario.

Comment: ooh wow, i was not even aware of `accumulate`!